AWS LoadBalancer + TargetGroup cannot access Spring Boot App in ECS
Not sure where I am going wrong:
Loadbalancer
LoadBalancer has a listener on HTTPS / 443
And Forwards to a Target Group
Target Group
Target Group has protocol HTTP / 80 configured
ECS
ECS has Spring Boot App with the host & container port mapped to port 9090
ECS Service is created that uses the existing LoadBalancer, and Target Group above
Security Groups
Loadbalancer Security Group - allows inbound on 443 - CIDR 0.0.0.0
ECS Security Group - allows inbound on port 9090 from LoadBalancer Security Group
Results
When I run the service:
Service runs.
Spins up 2 tasks as Running
The Target group reports both containers as Healthy (on the endpoint bff/actuator/health)
....But when I try to access that endpoint via the LoadBalancer
e.g. https://CloudFront/bff/actuator/health, I get a timeout / cannot access error (after 30 seconds)
I cannot figure out where I have gone wrong.
I inspect the CloudWatch logs, and its as if the request isn't getting through to the ECS Container.
Any ideas?
UPDATE
The ALB DNS works when I use that directly
https://LoadBalancerDNS/bff/actuator/health
(though I get a security warning since the ALB SSL cert expects the CloudFront URI)
The issue seems to be between CloudFront and the ALB, as this does not work:
https://CloudFrontRoute53DomainName/bff/actuator/health


Target Group has protocol HTTP / 80 configured
ECS has Spring Boot App with the host & container port mapped to port 9090 ECS Service is created that uses the existing Load Balancer, and Target Group above

Your Target Group is configured to send traffic to port 80 of the ECS task. Your ECS task is listening on port 9090, not port 80.
You need to configure your Target Group to forward traffic to the actual port the ECS task is listening on. In this case, that is port 9090.

It was one issue. The Target Group port stayed at 80 (it didn't have any bearing). Though I get your logic. The problem was the ALB - it had been misconfigured. It was in two subnets, but one of them I chose private, the other public- which is why i was getting intermittent results (1 in every 3). Seting both to public resolved the issue. It wasn't a CF issue, like I thought, or an ECS Target Group issue, but an ALB config issue

The only port configuration on the target group is the port that it forwards traffic to. It definitely needs to be configured to be the same as the port your backend servers are listening on.
